# How to display the labels for this Microsoft Visual Studio code?

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently taking a basic Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 course. The question asks me to import and read the contents from a text file to calculate and display the energy cost savings for a smart home. I am stuck starting on the comment, ' The formula for the average monthly savings inside the loop to repeat the process' on line 96 where I am supposed to calculate the average formula for the energy savings. I would also like to know how I can display the three labels. The name of the text formula is savings.txt. These are its contents:

```
January
38.17
February
41.55
March
27.02
April 
25.91
May
3.28
June
18.08
July
45.66
August
16.17
September
3.98
October
17.11
November
25.78
December
51.03
```

Are there any additional changes I can make to improve my code? I am new to this course and welcome any suggestions or examples.

Here is also a link to my rubric. Please let me know if you cannot access its contents:

https://maricopa-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/ric2084617_maricopa_edu/ETNr_-i-wllOr9zsRiNTyMIBG0CcNO1xICcaYVYmgKl7YA?e=tLq4Ng

I am certain I have the required variables declared. I am at a loss of how to apply them into the average formula. Should I add each of the costs from the text file or is there a more simple yet basic method to add them?

```
' Program Name: Smart Home Electric Savings
' Author:       Richard Lew
' Date:         October 27, 2019
' Purpose:      This Windows application opens a text file that lists the monthly savings of a smart home's electric bill in comparison to a previous year
'               without smart device activation. A smart thermostat, lighting system, and water heater were installed one year ago and the text file lists
'               the savings each month. The The user selects a month read from the text file and displays that month's electric bill savings. A Button object
'               displays the average monthly savings with the smart home devices and the month with the most significant savings.

Option Strict On

Public Class frmSavings
    ' Class Level Private variables
    Private _intMonthsOfSmartSavings As Integer = 12
    Public Shared _intSizeOfArray As Integer = 7
    Public Shared _strSavings(_intSizeOfArray) As String
    Private _strSavingsMonth(_intSizeOfArray) As String
    Private _decInitialBill(_intSizeOfArray) As Decimal
    Private _intMonth(_intSizeOfArray) As Integer

    Private Sub fromSavings_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' The frmSavings load event reads the savings text file and fills the label objects with the savings.

        ' Initialize an instance of the StreamReader object and declare variables
        Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "D:\CIS 159\VB_Student_Data_Files\Chapter 8\savings.txt"
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim intFill As Integer
        Dim strFileError As String = "The file is not available. Restart when the file is available."

        ' Verify the file exists
        If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
            objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
            ' Read the file line by line until the file is completed
            Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
                _strSavings(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
                _strSavingsMonth(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
                _decInitialBill(intCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(objReader.ReadLine())
                _intMonth(intCount) = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.ReadLine())
                intCount += 1
            Loop
            objReader.Close()

            ' The Monthly Savings Combo Box object is filled with the months of the savings
            For intFill = 0 To (_strSavingsMonth.Length - 1)
                cboMonthSavings.Items.Add(_strSavingsMonth(intFill))
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox(strFileError, , "Error")
            Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDisplayStatistics_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayStatistics.Click
        ' The btnDisplayStatistics click event calls the savings Sub procedures
        ' Declare variables
        Dim intSelectedMonth As Integer
        Dim strMissingSelection As String = "Missing Selection"
        Dim strSelectedMonthError As String = "Select a Month"
        Dim strSelectedMonth As String = ""
        Dim intMonthChoice As Integer
        Dim blnMonthIsSelected As Boolean = False

        ' If the Month Savings Combo Box is selected, then display the statistics
        If cboMonthSavings.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            intSelectedMonth = cboMonthSavings.SelectedIndex
        Else
            MsgBox(strSelectedMonthError, , strMissingSelection)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MonthSavingsComboBox(ByVal intMonth As Integer)
        ' This Sub procedure computes and displays the savings for the month selected
        ' Declare variables
        Dim intDoublePresentMonth As Integer
        Dim decDoubleAverage As Decimal = 0
        Dim decDoublePresentMonthValue As Decimal = 0
        Dim decDoubleSavings As Decimal
        Dim decAverageSavings As Decimal
        Dim decTotal As Decimal
        Dim decDoubleTotal As Decimal = 0.0D

        Dim strPresentSavingsMonth As String = ""
        Dim strPresentSavingsMonthValue As String = ""
        Dim decSavingsMonth As Decimal
        Dim strMonthOfSavings As String = ""
        Dim decAverageSavingsOfMonth As Decimal
        Dim decSignificantSavingsOfMonth As Decimal
        Dim strMonthOfSignificantSavings As String = ""

        ' The procedure MakeObjectsVisible is called to display the Form objects
        MakeObjectsVisible()
        'Display the values and quantity of the selected values
        lblDisplayMonthSavings.Text = "The electric savings for " & strPresentSavingsMonth & " is " & _strSavings(intMonth)
        lblDisplayAverageMonthlySavings.Text = "The average monthly savings: " & decAverageSavings.ToString("C0")
        lblDisplayMonthMostSignificantSavings.Text = _decInitialBill(intMonth) & " had the most significant monthly savings"

        ' The loop repeats for the life of the values
        For intDoublePresentMonth = 1 To _intMonthsOfSmartSavings
            ' The formula for the average monthly savings inside the loop to repeat the process
            decAverageSavings = decDoubleTotal / _intMonthsOfSmartSavings
            ' Displays the savings amounts
            cboMonthSavings.Items.Add(intDoublePresentMonth.ToString())
            ' Accumulates the total of the savings
            decTotal += decDoubleSavings



        Next










    End Sub

    Private Sub MakeObjectsVisible()
        ' This procedure displays the objects showing the results
        lblDisplayMonthSavings.Visible = True
        btnDisplayStatistics.Visible = True
        lblDisplayAverageMonthlySavings.Visible = True
        lblDisplayMonthMostSignificantSavings.Visible = True
        ' The previous data is removed
        cboMonthSavings.Items.Clear()
        lblDisplayMonthSavings.Text = ""
        lblDisplayAverageMonthlySavings.Text = ""
        lblDisplayMonthMostSignificantSavings.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub MnuFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFile.Click
        ' The mnuFile click event displays the mnuClear and and mnuExit buttons
    End Sub

    Private Sub MnuClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuClear.Click
        ' The mnuClear click event clears and resets the form
        cboMonthSavings.Items.Clear()
        lblDisplayMonthSavings.Text = ""
        lblDisplayAverageMonthlySavings.Text = ""
        lblDisplayMonthMostSignificantSavings.Text = ""
        lblDisplayMonthSavings.Visible = False
        lblDisplayAverageMonthlySavings.Visible = False
        lblDisplayMonthMostSignificantSavings.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub MnuExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
        ' The mnuExit click event closes the application
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Update: This is the code for the error message on line 37 about the incorrect input:                 _decInitialBill(intCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(objReader.ReadLine())

Comment: try a dictionary of string,decimal it should be working great for your example, btw i couldn't see where you're skipping a line so that _decInitialBill won't take the months and try to convert them to decimal that's why you are getting the error, the error should say January could not be converted to decimal...

Comment: or if you want to have 2 lists where first contains months and 2nd contains decimals, use `mod 2 = 0` on the line index inside a loop, it will tell you if the index is even or odd which will tell you if the line is month or decimal

Comment: Now I see. Now that I've looked over it again, some of the sections of the codes were also in the wrong areas. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: Anytime, if you still couldn't​ get it done let us know